# How do I write console.log in js_of_ocaml?

Tags: ocaml, js-of-ocaml

How do I write console.log in js_of_ocaml? `print_endline` might go to the console, but I want access to trace, error, etc. Can I just define `console` as an external object?

This does not work for me:

```
let console = Js.Unsafe.global##console
```

Fails with:

> TypeError: N.console is not a function test.js:255:30

This fails with the same error:

```
class type console = object
  method log : Js.js_string Js.t -> unit Js.meth
end

let _ =
  let console : console = Js.Unsafe.global##console in
  let here : Js.js_string Js.t = Js.string "here" in
  console#log here
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The JavaScript console object is inside the Firebug module, API here: https://ocsigen.org/js_of_ocaml/3.5.0/api/js_of_ocaml/Js_of_ocaml/Firebug/class-type-console/index.html

Example:

```
open Js_of_ocaml
open Js
let here : js_string t = string "here" in 
Firebug.console##log here;
```

NB: Just writing `Firebug.console##log "here"` will dump an object, not the JavaScript string "here".